# Splitting up a menu to allow separate hover colors

Tags: html, css

I am having problems splitting up a menu to allow me to give each button of the menu it's own unique color and hover color. So far, this code only allows me to set universal colors that affect all the menu choices. I would really appreciate if someone could tell me what to change/add to my code, in order to give each choice it's own color.

I have made a link to Jsbin with the code I am using, so you can see the menu "live" - this might be better for you to see how it's working. Here is the link: http://jsbin.com/ivoqoh/1/edit

Again, my goal is to give each individual menu choice (Page 1, Page 2, etc.) a unique color and hover color.

Comment: Keep in mind you can't use `z-index` without an element being positioned (relative, absolute/fixed)

Comment: if you are trying to style the anchor, then just add a class to each anchor tag and target them that way to have different colours

Answer (score 0):

You are affecting all of the menu items because you are using a class as a style. To effect menu items individually you need to assign a unique ID to each element. In your case it would be best to wrap a div around each link and give the divs unique IDs so that you can change styles like the back ground not just the style for the links themselves. In your CSS document you can then stylize each div individually and the style will cascade down into its children (your  tags).

Example:

```
<div id="firstMenuItem"><a href... /></div>
```

CSS

```
#firstMenuItem {
    background-color:#111111;
}
```

To achieve responding to user events in real time on the web requires the use of JavaScript. Essentially what you want to say in this language is, "when the user mouses over a particular div, change the background color of the menu button."

Since you would like to do the same type of process repetitively with different DOM objects and colors, then you would benefit by writing a function and passing arguments in for the value of the div you would like to change and the color you would like to change it to.

```
<script type="JavaScript/text">

changeMenuBackground(currentDivID, desiredColor) {

// get the current div element
var div = getElementById(currentDivID);

div.style.backgroundColor = desiredColor;

}
<\script>
```

There are two moments in the user interaction when the background color of the div needs to change. The first is when the user has the mouseOver the button and the second is when the mouse leaves the button (in us known as mouseOut). To every div that you want to change the background to you would have to change the background to the nw color on mouseOver and on mouseOut.

Example

```
<div id="firstMenuItem" onmouseover="changeMenuBackground(#firstMenuItem,#333333);" onmouseout="changeMenuBackground(#firstMenuItem,#111111);"><a href="...." /><\div>
```

There are many different ways to achieve what you want to do, but all of them require the use of JavaScript. This way should do just fine, although you may be able to make it more efficient when tailored to your specific code. Insert the script tags just beneath your CSS styles or CSS sheets but before the body of you page. You must supply the div id preceded by the # symbol and the color you wish to change to for every div in the format i specified above for this function to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far - although I haven't been able to get it working yet. I have made a link to Jsbin with the code I am using, so you can see the menu "live" - this might be better for you to see how it's working. Here is the link: http://jsbin.com/ivoqoh/1/edit

Again, my goal is to give each individual menu choice (Page 1, Page 2, etc.) a unique color and hover color. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may insert color by just add "color" command in your input or use css to set color.

HTML:

```
<a href="#slide-panel-1">Page 1</a>
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="slide-control-2" color="put your color"/>
```

or
CSS:

```
.radio-set
{
background-color: "your color";
color: "your color";
}
```

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far - although I haven't been able to get it working yet. I have made a link to Jsbin with the code I am using, so you can see the menu "live" - this might be better for you to see how it's working. Here is the link: http://jsbin.com/ivoqoh/1/edit

Again, my goal is to give each individual menu choice (Page 1, Page 2, etc.) a unique color and hover color. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers posted here so far have give the answer, and they're all valid. Pretty much, if you want each individual element to have their own special colors you'll need to apply a unique ID to each element, and then apply CSS against that specific ID.

You've defined your menu items using anchor tags (`<a>`) like this:

```
<a href="#slide-panel-2">Page 2</a>
```

To style page 2 specifically, you'd need to add an ID to page 2:

```
<a href="#slide-panel-1" id="two">Page 2</a>
```

And then apply styles explicitly for page 2:

```
#two {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

You'll need to do the same thing for each page. See the update to your JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/ivoqoh/3/edit).

Comment: I am not so strong in CSS yet, so I apologize I am a bit dense here... :) But I can see what you have done and it works as I want it to, so thanks a lot and thanks to everyone who posted!

Comment: I just have one more question regarding this. What you did added static colors to each menu element, but no hover colors. Whenever I add 'a' or 'a:hover' to the style you made, nothing happens. How would I go about making them react on hover?

Comment: @Peter `#two:hover` would target page 2 on hover. `a:hover` is a generic "any `<a>` element on hover."

Answer (score 0):

u need add class all  and then to set the color scheme.